# mIRC Need to determine if 25 hours have passed since last script execution

Tags: mirc

Basically I have this script so far:

```
on 1:TEXT:*some text*:#:{
 if(($time(hh)-25) > $lasttime ) {
   This code gets executed only once per 25 hours
   $lasttime = $time(hh)
 }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly but if I am I need to know how to set $lasttime if its not already set, and if there is anyway to keep $lasttime set when mirc is closed and re opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, save the last time it was said in a permanent variable (`set %last_time ...`) and check against that the next time. global mIRC %variables are kept even after close/reopen.

Comment: To be clear, the `set` command is what makes the variable global. Local variables also start with a percent sign, but you use `var %variable` instead of `set %variable`.

Comment: @Kylar: Also, `var %variable = value`, against `set %variable value`